# Feed me and Guzzle: Use session cookies

Tags: plugin-feedme, cookies, configuration, guzzle

I am using Feed me to import data from a Filemaker server via a self made Craft module. The import works well. I fail however to import the image files from the Filemaker server: Feed me gets their address but copying them leads to a 401 error.

The request of the first image file is always responded with an 302 redirect and a `Set-Cookie | X-FMS-Session-Key=…` command. All following requests of the sesssion and for the session only must send the cookie. Otherwise a 401 error is thrown.

I tried to configure Feed me/Guzzle to get and use that cookie with the `requestOptions` option in a `feed-me.php`configuration file. From [the Guzzle documentation](https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html#cookies) I unserstand that I need to set a jar and tell the request to use that jar. In the configuration file however I can only set a map of settings but not the needed `$jar = new \GuzzleHttp\Cookie\CookieJar();`.

How can I advice Guzzle to read and use the session cookie? Thank you very much for your help!